# Mysql Index to Ignore Spaces and Capitalization?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, normalization

I have an unique index on a text field and I was wondering if there is anyway I can tell it to ignore case and extra spaces.  I do some preprocessing to normalize the data before inserting but I would still like it to count these two

```
"This is  the title of  My data"
"this is the title of my data"
```

as the same and only allow for one of them.  If there is a way to do this at the index level then that would be great but if not I guess I can try to make the preprocessing more strict to normalize all incoming data.  I have a bunch of old data which would have to be passed through whatever normalization again or else I will continue to get duplicate entries so I would much prefer some way to fix this at the MySQL index level.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character case has become so complex with so many languages.  If you need to preserve exactly what was typed is to make two columns with the typed text and normalized text... as in trimmed, lcase, etc.  Search on the normalized column, display the user's column

Answer (score 0):

sigh, computed indexes.. not yet in mySQL.
Would converting to case help eg. LCASE(searchItem)

..and perhaps UPDATE myTABLE set myFIELD to LCASE(myFIELD)

Comment: Your answer means there is no way to do what I want in MySQL? That I must do it in the preprocessing level?